# Direct Message Maximum amount of members

Tags: apex, api, chatter, direct-messaging

I want to be able to send files to a whole bunch of contacts. I want to know, is there a limit to the number of members that can be added into it?

```
ConnectApi.DirectMessageCapabilityInput dmInput = new ConnectApi.DirectMessageCapabilityInput();
dmInput.membersToAdd = membersIdsToAdd;
```

`membersIdsToAdd` would be the amount of members i will be sending my files to.

Comment: see [ConnectApi Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connect_api_limits.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I've personally tested this and the limit of members i can send a Direct Message to is 15 people. It's not on its documentation...